# Cocoa - XCode style notification window

Tags: cocoa

Is the semi-transparant notification window which XCode 4 shows on Snow Leopard and on Lion a standard Cocoa control or is it something custom?  I've seen more and more apps with similarly styled popups, and don't want to go about reinventing something if a much cleaner implementation exists in Cocoa.  If this is a standard control, could someone tell me the name or point me to the documentation for it?

This is the popup window I am referring to:

[image: XCode's Build Succeeded window]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is custom but Matt Gemmell has sample code at http://mattgemmell.com/source. It's called RoundedFloatingPanel.

Comment: Darn, that's what I have already done.  As the popularity of this window has been increasing, I was starting to think I was missing a built in control.